# How to safely convert text to html code in a way that makes links clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Example input:

`Hello! Please go to example.com! <script>/*this should not be executed*/</script>`

Example output:

`Hello! Please go to <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>! &ltscript&gt/*this should not be executed*/&lt/script&gt`

I am using Javascript. If this is already answered, please give me a link.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify is useful

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, https://linkify.js.org/ works the way I wanted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).